# What's the easiest way to process incoming email and add it to a queue on a Linux server?

Tags: email, parsing, incoming-mail

What's the easiest way to process incoming email? Our objective is to get email into a Resque queue. We've explored and integrated a lot of options, like piping email through Postfix into Ruby (which turned out to be unreliable), piping email through Google App Engine back to our server (which turned out to be shaky), and using Sendgrid (which is expensive.)

I'm trying to explore other ways to get email processed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the email is received and hosted by an IMAP-capable server (Gmail is good enough), then the messages can be retrieved and processed once and again from almost any programming language using standard libraries.